# js alert that tells css animation is over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a box and a rotation css animation is applied to, i want to add a js function that gives me an alert when the animation is over, how can i do that using webkitTransitionEnd?

Here is my code:

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 100px;
}
.box:hover {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's actually not possible with css, but since your animation is *infinite* and fires on `hover` event, you could listen to the `mouseleave` event (animation stops when element is no longer hovered).

```js
$('.box').mouseleave(function() {
  console.log('animation has ended');
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 100px;
}

.box:hover {
    animation-name: rotate; 
    animation-duration: 2s; 
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Depends though, hover triggers an animation, but the mouse can leave before the animation is complete

Comment: @SterlingArcher Depends what do you mean with *animation is complete*. I guess it is *completed* when it has just ended (mouse has left the element). The situation would be quite contrary though, if only the animation wasn't *infinite*.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually add an event listener for things that have fully animated.  The event is called `animationend`. Assuming you are open to using JavaScript, you could do something like:

```
var x = document.getElementByClass("box");

// Code for Chrome, Safari and Opera

x.addEventListener("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
  console.log("event had ended");
});

// Standard syntax

x.addEventListener("animationend", function(){
  console.log("event had ended");
});
```